# How to use my GitHub Repository for OpenShift

Tags: git, openshift

I am new to OpenShift and don't know how to use my private remote GitHub repository with OpenShift.  I would like OpenShift to monitor my private remote GitHub repository and kick off a build every time I push to my private remote GitHub repository; and provided the build was successful, I would like OpenShift to deploy my app.

Does anybody have step-by-step instructions on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

While I understand the reasoning, it might not be the best way to go as you might not get the results your looking for. I use Github as well for multiple OpenShift projects and the way I have it set up is as follows:

1. Create OpenShift app with `rhc app create <cartridge> -a <appname>`, which should clone the OS repo to my local machine.
2. I then cd into my local repo and add the GitHub repo as a remote:

`git remote add ghupstream <link to github git repo>`

When I'm developing I'll make all my changes to github and once I'm ready to push to "production" I'll push my changes to master on my OpenShift repo which will in turn kick off a build. Its not fully automatic but I like it that way. This ensures that not every push is sent to production and that my code will only enter production when I manually introduce it.

However if you're looking for a fully automated solution. I'm working on a OpenShift Blog post that will walk you through using Jenkins and GitHub to accomplish what your asking.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I am looking for an fully automated solution.  Will your blog post describe how to use a private GitHub repo instead of OpenShift's Git repo?  BTW, I am find with OpenShift using the its own Jenkins, just as lone as there is away to use my private GitHub repo.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty reasonable guide here: https://nwillc.wordpress.com/2015/07/03/your-existing-github-to-openshift-with-travis-ci

basically:

1. Create a DiY OpenShift app
2. Strip that app down to just it’s control structure.
3. Commit and push to the OpenShift git
4. Add the OpenShift git repo as a remote origin to my local clone of my GitHub repo
5. Pull from the OpenShift origin
6. Resolve any merge issues (both had a README.md), commit
7. copy rhc .git local config from OpenShift git to local github git
8. Add a new single remote alias for combining GitHub and OpenShift
9. Push to combined remote
10. Verify GitHub and OpenShift gits both looked right